# Concentric layout of small circles in a large circle

Tags: algorithm, math

From this [page](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2013/sm/c3sm00073g) I found this short description of a circular layout of small circles, forming a larger one.

The described result is this:

[image]

And the description says this:

"...a circular object is represented by a collection of discrete blobs packed in concentric rings; the blobs have radial separation s, and points are separated on the circle by an arc length of s. For this illustration, s = 0.08R and the total number of points is N = 534."

The question: What would be the math logic required to achieve this sort of circular layout, assuming the smaller circles can be points?

Thank you,
Claudia

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I can't see how this fits to SO.

Comment: The question is regarding the math/logic to achieve this. Which I believe is stated in the last paragraph. Should I clarify it somehow?

Comment: The problem with the question is that you haven't made it clear what you do and don't know how to do.  For example, is it the logic of which circles to draw and where?  Is it the mathematics of converting between polar and rectangular co-ordinates?  Is it the API for drawing one of the small circles?  If you don't make it clear what you're having trouble with, then the only reasonable answer would be a complete solution; and I don't think anybody wants to code that for you.

Comment: Thank you David, I edited the question to hopefully better explain what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two nested loops; one which tracks the radius, and one which tracks the angle at which to draw a point at that radius. Inside the outer loop, calculate how many points you want to draw; then draw them inside the inner loop.

For the outer loop, let the radius `r` increase by a constant value each time.

For the inner loop, if you're going to draw `n` points at a radius of `r`, around a centre `(cx,cy)`, you should let `i` loop from `0` up to `n-1`, and draw a point at

```
(cx + r * cos (2 * pi * i / n), cy + r * sin (2 * pi * i / n))
```

Comment: And, for each iteration of inner circle, should I add "s" (as described) to the radius "r"? Assuming I start from the inside outwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what `s` is supposed to mean in the question, but yes, for each iteration of the outer loop, you'll add some constant on to `r`.

Answer (score 1):

- Hi Claudia, solutions of that kind of problem are independent of the size of the little blobs. You may regard them just as dimension-less points. Further on, you have radii 0, s, 2s, ..., Ns, with circumferences 0, 2pi*s, 2pi*2x, ..., 2pi*Ns. Given the distance s you have to ride from one blob to the next, following along an arbitrary circle, there are (theoretically) 0, 2pi, 2pi*2, 2pi*N blobs possible on the N'th circle, but because pi=3.142856..., one has to find some suitable integer number near 2pi*N, the real shape of such images depend on the exact algorithm, how the blobs are successively drawn, by hand, or by computer program. Think about symmetries, above, you have (nearly) hexagonal symmetry, but others are possible, too. Regards, M.

Comment: - Maybe my hometown has some undue Gaussian curvature? Regards, M.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the center circle and the pentagon that surrounds it, the pattern is strongly hexagonal, indicating that the circle is divided into 6 equal parts of 60 degrees each. The center of each small circle is computed with the trig functions

```
x = r*cos(angle);  
y = r*sin(angle);
```

The trick is to choose the right angles.  For the inner most ring it appears that the angles are 0 and 30 (repeated 6 times to complete the hexagon). The next ring uses angles 0, 20, 40.  I didn't check all of the rings, but the pattern apparently uses a delta angle equal to 60 / n, where n starts at 2 for the innermost hexagonal ring.